# Can't change relationship properties in Core Data Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I get "Not Applicable" in the Data Model inspector.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/73984/make-app-like-runkeeper-part-1) and when I try to change the relationship between two entities I don't have the option.

[image: Screenshot]

I can't figure out if I'm missing something or if this is just a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change editor style to graph.
2. Click on property in relation part of table.
3. Click inspector on right side.
4. Change as you like.

Edit.

I added picture, where all the elements are

[image: picture]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but its just the same, no options appear on the side.

Comment: I have xCode 8.2.1 and I have the option

Comment: thanks for the pic, its the same thing im doing here but nothing shows up http://imgur.com/a/kGT2M

Comment: Have you tried restarting xCode? If so, you can go to generated classes try to change relation from object to array of object and build. If this still doesnt work try to delete derived data/caches in your library. If still nothing try to reinstall xCode.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was creating a Master-Detail App, the thing was that I deleted the Event entity that is created by default. That error I think it wasnt letting me see the other properties. I created the project again and didnt delete that entity (as the tutorial says) and is working fine. Really don't have any idea what this event does. Thanks again!

Comment: In xCode 12, this is working for me. But why only in the graph style editor? Why? Why Apple, why?

Answer (score 1):

This situation occur whenever we create same destination tabs insidethe xcode.

step1: Check how many tabs are open of same .xcDataModelID
step2: if it's more then 1 then cancel out the tabs & try again

Problem fixed!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had renamed the `.xcdatamodeld` file. I had to delete it and recreate it